# scala case class hashcode with circular references

Tags: scala, hashcode, case-class

As Scala documentation says, "Case classes are compared by structure and not by reference".

I was trying to create a linked list with a loop in it, then add a node from this looped list to a mutable set. When using a regular class, it succeeded, but with a case class I hit a stack overflow.

I'm curious why Scala doesn't *first* check for reference before checking for structure. My thinking is that that if the reference is the same then the structure is guaranteed to be the same, so this can be a shortcut as well as allow for circular references.

Code:

```
object CaseClassHashcodeExample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val head = new ListNode(0)
    head.appendToTail(1)
    head.appendToTail(2)
    head.appendToTail(3)
    head.next.next.next = head.next
    val set = collection.mutable.Set[ListNode]()
    set.add(head)
    assert(set(head))
  }
}

case class ListNode(var data: Int, var next: ListNode = null) {
  def appendToTail(d: Int): Unit = {
    val end = new ListNode(d)
    var cur = this
    while (cur.next != null)
      cur = cur.next
    cur.next = end
  }
}
```

Comment: Mutable value or var should not be used as case class properties

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I put the var in a regular class ListNode, and wanted to ask about the hashcode when changing it to a case class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm curious why Scala doesn't first check for reference before checking for structure

Well, what *exactly* do you want it to check? The current generated code looks something like

```
def hashCode() = 31 * data.hashCode() + next.hashCode()
```

One thing you could try is

```
def hashCode() = 31 * data.hashCode() + (if (next eq this) 0 else next.hashCode())
```

but it wouldn't actually help: in your case it isn't `next` which is the same as `this`, it's `next.next`.

`next.hashCode` doesn't know it's called from `this.hashCode` and so can't compare its own `next` to `this`.

You could create a helper method taking a set of "seen" objects into account:

```
def hashCode() = hashCode(Nil)
def hashCode(seen: List[ListNode]) = if (seen.exists(_ eq this)) 0 else 31 * data.hashCode() + next.hashCode(this :: seen)
```

But this both greatly slows down the common case, and is hard to actually get right.

EDIT: for `equals`, reference equality *is* checked first in case classes.

```
class NeverEq {
  override def equals(other: Any) = false
}

case class Test(x: NeverEq)

val x = Test(new NeverEq())
println(x == x)
```

prints `true` and would be `false` if only structure was compared.

But it doesn't actually help with circular references. Let's say you have a `ListNode` type without `data` to simplify which implements equality like this:

```
def equals(other: Any) = (this eq other) || (other match {
  case other: ListNode => this.next == other.next
})
```

and want to check if `node1 == node2` where `node1.next` is `node2` and vice versa:

```
node1 <--> node2
```

1. `node1 == node2` reduces to `(node1 eq node2) || (node1.next == node2.next)`.
2. `node1 eq node2` is false, so that reduces to `node1.next == node2.next`, that is `node2 == node1`.
3. `node2 eq node1` is false, so that reduces to `node2.next == node1.next`, that is `node1 == node2`...

Comment: OK with the help of this answer I think I get where my thinking went wrong. I was mixing what hashcode and equals are supposed to do. My thinking was that to see if two instances of a case class are equal, you could first compare them using default behavior for regular classes, and only if those are _not_ equal, _then_ fall back to checking the structure of the objects. However, hashcode just has one object and needs to consistently return the same integer for it, whether you do that by reference _or_ by the structure of it.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks Alexey! In this particular case, this helped me solve the problem a different way in which I actually do care that `equals` works that way, because I end up comparing a node to itself through two different references.